# Responsive two-column layout positioning

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to build a responsive layout for desktop and mobile screens using bootstrap 3. While using `.col-XX-push-X` I'm having problems as the columns are still using the space of their height.

I'm trying to produce this:
[image]

and what I'm getting is this:
[image]

This is my relevant code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="campaign-description-section"
                     class="section campaign-description-section col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-push-6 col-lg-push-6">
                    Campaign Description Section
                </div>
                <div id="shirt-styles-section"
                     class="section shirt-styles-section col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-pull-6 col-lg-pull-6">
                    Shirt Styles Section
                </div>
                <div id="color-size-section"
                     class="section color-size-section col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-push-6 col-md-push-6">
                    Color Size Section
                </div>
                <div id="price-section"
                     class="section price-section col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-push-6 col-md-push-6">
                    Price Section
                </div>
                <div id="attention-banner"
                     class="section attention-banner col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-push-6 col-md-push-6">
                    Attention Banner Section
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is the link to [code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJoeyV)

Answer (score 1):

`col-{size}-pull` / `col-{size}-push` per se, do not give any size.

Add then `col-md-6 col-lg-6` respectively to the first two sections.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
<div id="shirt-styles-section" class="section shirt-styles-section col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
   Shirt Styles Section
</div>
<div id="campaign-description-section" class="section campaign-description-section col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
   Campaign Description Section
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i've never used `____-pull` so i have try without what did you think about it :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div id="shirt-styles-section"
                 class="section shirt-styles-section col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                Shirt Styles Section
            </div>
            <div id="campaign-description-section"
                 class="section campaign-description-section col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                Campaign Description Section
            </div>

            <div id="color-size-section"
                 class="section color-size-section col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-push-6 col-md-push-6">
                Color Size Section
            </div>
            <div id="price-section"
                 class="section price-section col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-push-6 col-md-push-6">
                Price Section
            </div>
            <div id="attention-banner"
                 class="section attention-banner col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-push-6 col-md-push-6">
                Attention Banner Section
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```